# Excel file import date as exponential (e.g. 1.74E+09) value to date format?

Tags: excel, date, format

I opened an Excel file with a column `Time` having date and time as values. When uploaded into Excel, though, the dates I used to have are now represented in exponential notation, e.g. `1.74E+09` and `1.75E+09`). What date format can I use in Excel to convert these numbers to something following `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss`, or at the very least, `yyyy/mm/dd`?

Comment: What did the value look like before the import?

Comment: I actually didn't have the file before. So I just received the file and opened it to see `1.74E+09`, etc.

Comment: Set that column as General or Number and post the results because the 1.74E+09 gives us 1740000000 which is meaningless to us.  There must be other numbers that are hidden by the scientific notation.

Comment: An example: `1.74E+09` is `1735883904` in the function field (or General format).

Comment: That does not look like any date format I know.  You will need to get your hands on the import and see how it is being translated.

Comment: That's what I figured. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the date/time was encoded into the integer.  This is only an example:

- the left-most 5 digits are the date
- the right-most 5 digits are the time

with data in **A1**, in **B1**:

```
=TEXT(MID(A1,1,5),"mm/dd/yyyy") & "  " & TEXT(TIME(MID(A1,6,1),MID(A1,7,2),RIGHT(A1,2)),"hh:mm:ss")
```

[image]